# problema con extraer datos del formulario con jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tengo este ejemplo de formulario con jquery y javascript en el que el usuario puede agregar formularios para agregar mas teléfonos si lo desea y eliminarlos por igual pero quiero que al enviar el formulario este mande un mensaje, no guardo los datos en una base de datos, simplemente quiero usarlos en un mensaje despues de dar click en el boton enviar pero me dice que es indefinido

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Titulo de Página</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<!---->
<body>


    <div id="formulario">
        <div class="">
            <h2>Envio de comentatios</h2>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="">Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" id="nombre"><br>

            <label for="">Apellido:</label>
            <input type="text" id="apellido"><br>

            <label for="">Correo:</label>
            <input type="text" id="correo"><br>

            <label for="">Comentario:</label>
            <textarea></textarea><br>

            <fieldset id="telefonos">
                <legend><strong>Telefonos</strong></legend>
                <div class="">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="casa">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="">
            <button id="btnEnviar">Enviar Formulario.</button>
            <button id="btnAgregarTelefono">Agregar Telefono</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#btnAgregarTelefono').click(function(){
                $('#telefonos').append('<div> <input type="text" placeholder="otro" /><button class="borrarTelefono" onclick="eliminarTelefono(this);"><strong>X<strong> </button> </div>');
            });
            $('#btnEnviar').click(function(){
                var nombre = $('#nombre').attr('value');
                var apellido = $('#apellido').attr('value');
                    $('<h1>' +nombre +' '+ apellido + ' </br> Gracias por enviar tu comentario. </h1>').replaceAll('#formulario');
            });
        });
        function eliminarTelefono(telefono){
            $(telefono).parent().remove();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

tengo entendido que la función `.attr('value');` me extrae el valor del formulario en donde tengo id que seleccione en el selector pero no me lo esta substrayendo

```
.error{
    border: solid 2px red;
    color: red;
}
.borrarTelefono{
    color: red;
}
#formulario{
    background-color: #E5EECC;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
    color: #000000;
    padding:50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 40px;
    width: 616px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo prueba con:

```
var nombre = $('#nombre').val();
var apellido = $('#apellido').val();
```

Un abrazo :D

Comment: gracias @PieroPajares

Comment: No hay problema @Efrainrodc! si puedes darle como respuesta correcta estaría agradecido también :D